# Topk values in LogQL

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I need some help with Loki. I`ve got json logs like following

```
{"message": {"reason": "reason1"...}}
{"message": {"reason": "reason2"...}}
```

And I need to print top N reasons. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following LogQL

```
topk(N, sum by (reason) (count_over_time({filename="xxxxx"} | json [1d])))
```

Comment: Can you explain why `count_over_time` is required? Should all (not necessarily just `[1d]` worth) of the reasons within whatever the timeframe is be counted? (Fyi: I am a complete amateur at using logql!)

Comment: The "count_over_time(xxx [1d])" will effectively count the lines in a one day window, the "sum by (reason) (xxx)" will break this count by "reason" label and, finally, the "topk(xxx)" will select the top reasons.

Comment: Thanks for replying - could you expand on what it means by a "one day window"? In my experience thus far the timeframe for querying logs is defined external to the LogQL query, in the Grafana ui. It confuses me that I specify a timeframe external to the query, and then another timeframe (e.g. `[1d]`) within the query. I'm trying to express a point of confusion - let me know if you understand what I'm asking! :)

Comment: The UI timeframe will define how many metrics will be got from Loki to be shown. The "1d" timeframe is the moving windows used by the "count_over_time" to count the lines, It goes counting lines until de "1d" limit is reached, then, at each timestep, it subtracts the value at the beginning (if there is one) of the window and sums the new value at the end (if there is one).

Comment: Ah that clarifies, thanks very much!